# Encode URL for AJAX POST data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was using encodeURIComponent to encode an URL but I'm getting 500 SERVER ERROR on some urls, I'm sure the problem is in the encoding since removing the data solves the error completely.

How do I encode the URL so that I can retrieve it in the other end and not have problems in the call?

```
    $.ajax({type:'POST',url: "/insert-url.php", data: 'url='+encodeURIComponent(link)',
        success:function(data_response){
            }
        });
```

Comment: to be supersafe when transfering data use base64 encoding

Comment: This happens most of the times when there is a syntax error in the source page. Check if there remains any one which can happen for encoding

Comment: There is a single quote after "encodeURIComponent(link)'," that shouldn't be there..

Comment: Could you post a URI with which these errors occur?

Comment: Use encodeURI instead of encodeURIComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',url: "/insert-url.php", 
        data: 'url='+encodeURIComponent(link)**-->'<---**,
        success:function(data_response){
        }
});
```

a ' too much